# Outputting YouTube API data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-api

I'm trying to retrieve all the playlists from a certain channel, and printing out the name of each playlist in my AngularJS app.

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

myApp.factory('videoApi', function ($resource) {
  return $resource(            'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists', 
         {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
         { 
          get: { 
            method: 'JSONP', 
            params: { 
              part: 'snippet',
              channelId: '**removed**',
              maxResults: 50,
              key: '**removed**' },
            isArray : false,
          } 
        } );
});

myApp.controller('WebService', function ($scope, videoApi) {
   $scope.playlist = videoApi.get();
});
```

This is what I have now, and when I call on {{playlist}} it displays all the json information correctly. However, I want to only print the title. I tried {{playlist.items.snippet.title}} but that didn't work. I'm hoping someone can lend me a hand here.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here's the HTML code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="crashcourse.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="app">
     <div ng-controller="WebService">
        {{playlist.items[0].snippet.title}}
     </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: My guess would be one of those properties contains an array, and you aren't referencing an item in that array properly.

Comment: As @KevinB says. `items` is an array. Probably playlist.items[0].snippet.title would get you the first title etc?

Comment: @theduck I tried that out, but unfortunately still nothing it being printed.

Comment: how does your HTML look like?

Comment: ``{{playlist.items[0].snippet.title}}``  should print out the title!

Comment: and you don't need ``isArray: false`` for the ``get`` action! @see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: @BettySt i added my HTML, i dont think it's wrong from there. (I just removed the [0] from next to items since it wasnt working)

Comment: you don't need the ``ng-repeat="playlist in playlists"`` playlist is an object not an array

Comment: @BettySt I took it out, but it still didnt print anything. I edited my post to include the header of my HTML as well, in case if I might've done something wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your HTML like this:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="WebService">
    <div ng-repeat="item in playlist.items">
        {{item.snippet.title}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the response has an items array! 
See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list

Comment: It's still not working...sorry for putting you through this trouble, I really appreciate all the help though.

Also, when I right click and inspect the page, it shows ng-repeat as being commented out for some reason.

Comment: can you look in the network console what the actual response is from youtube?

Comment: i'm not quite sure..i havent read a network response before. I also forgot to mention, if i just put {{playlist}} it displays all the JSON information at once.

Comment: ok can you post the actual JSON you can see when putting {{playlist}} here please ;)

Comment: wow, i just realized that in the code you gave me it said "playlist.items" and not "playlists.items"..it worked now!! THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH!! You are amazing!!